# Windows seach index always excluds harddrive D

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-search

I got the strange problem, that the windows search index always excludes my second harddrive althrough I have selected it to be indexed. Also rebuild the index doesn't change anything.

[image: Screenshot overview] 
[image: Screenshow edit]

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried to rebuild the index?  [Force Windows 7 to rebuild my search index?](https://www.askdavetaylor.com/force_windows_7_to_rebuild_my_search_index/)

Comment: Yes but it excludes the hold hard drive d

Comment: I wasn't able to solve this problem but it now works again after i reinstalled windows